# OpenSSH on Windows 10 closes connection when public key is present

Tags: windows, openssh, public-key

I just installed OpenSSH on my Win10 machine to be able to execute commands on it from my Raspberry Pi running the latest Raspbian.

I can login fine from my MacBook and my Pi to the SSH server on my Win10 machine with password. However if I generate a public key by `ssh-keygen -t rsa` on the Pi or the Mac which I want to use to be able to login without password (which for instance works fine from the Pi TO two of my Macs!) the openSSH server on Win10 immediately closes the connection. I can only connect then using `-o PubkeyAuthentication=no`. With this method I also copied the pubkeys to the Win10 machine but no changes... as soon as they are present on the client machine this is happening.

The log I am getting when trying to login is:
`OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u3, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 90.0.0.2 [90.0.0.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 26:5e:3e:02:91:90:15:8a:1d:3f:ff:e1:2a:2b:33:8b
debug1: Host '90.0.0.2' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
****USAGE WARNING****
This is a private computer system. This computer system, including all
related equipment, networks, and network devices (specifically including
Internet access) are provided only for authorized use. This computer system
may be monitored for all lawful purposes, including to ensure that its use
is authorized, for management of the system, to facilitate protection against
unauthorized access, and to verify security procedures, survivability, and
operational security. Monitoring includes active attacks by authorized entities
to test or verify the security of this system. During monitoring, information
may be examined, recorded, copied and used for authorized purposes. All
information, including personal information, placed or sent over this system
may be monitored.
Use of this computer system, authorized or unauthorized, constitutes consent to monitoring of this system. Unauthorized use may subject you to criminal prosecution. Evidence of unauthorized use collected during monitoring may be used for administrative, criminal, or other adverse action. Use of this system constitutes consent to monitoring for these purposes.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa
Connection closed by 90.0.0.2`

Comment: No idea anyone? :/

Comment: One last bump. :/

Comment: This looks like you are connecting to an external host and not your windows machine.  Are you able to describe your network setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now switched to "PowershellServer", which is free for privat and one-connection-at-a-time-use (which is exactly my situation) and supports pub key authentication. Works well and is easy to set up since it has a nice gui.